# Expansion of Galaxy's Caused by Electromagnetic forces

Tags: space-expansion, galaxies

From my limited physics knowledge i know that gravity when compared to Electromagnetic forces is very weak... So if every object is polarized (positive and negative separation), then on a bigger level shouldn't galaxy's have this too?
So then this could explain why galaxy's are repealing away from each other with their like polarity, seeing the force of gravity is no match for the electromagnetic forces acting on them. 
Just a thought though. Would be great to see if it is wrong and the real physics behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if every object is polarized (positive and negative separation), then on a bigger level shouldn't galaxy's have this too?

In general macroscopic objects aren't polarised.

For example a single water molecule is polarised - the hydrogen atoms are more positive than the oxygen aton - so the molecule has an electric dipole moment. However in a bowl of water or a block of ice the dipoles from all the $10^{23}$ molecules cancel out and the water/ice has no net dipole moment.

So we would not expect an object as big as a galaxy to have a significant dipole moment and this cannot be an explanation for why galaxies are moving away from each other.